# oracle sql stored procedure that creates temporary local cache of number(10)

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I need to do several select statements in a stored procedure and then update tables based of the key retrieved in the select statements at the end of the procedure. What is the best way to do this in a stored procedure, I looked into global temporary tables and it doesn't seem to be the best way.

Just an fyi, for the select statements I am using a cursor in a loop, that is how I hope to update the local temp cache/table.

Thanks for any help in advance.

```
create or replace procedure...
begin

select primary_keys from table..
-- save these keys to a temp cache or table

select primary_keys from table
-- save these additional keys to a temp cache or table

update table set field = 1 where primary_key in (select keys in temp cache or table)

commit;
delete temp cache or table
```

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A global temporary table (GTT) is a perfectly fine way to do it if you do not know how many keys you might have because a GTT will spool to temporary storage rather than blow up your session memory.

But if you are absolutely sure that the size is small, then a nested table can do it, eg

```
SQL> set serverout on
SQL> declare
  2    emplist sys.odcinumberlist;
  3    l_count int;
  4  begin
  5    select empno
  6    bulk collect into emplist
  7    from scott.emp;
  8
  9    for i in 1 .. emplist.count
 10    loop
 11      dbms_output.put_line(emplist(i));
 12    end loop;
 13
 14    select count(*)
 15    into   l_count
 16    from   scott.emp
 17    where  sal > 2000
 18    and  empno in ( select column_value from table(emplist));
 19
 20    dbms_output.put_line('l_count='||l_count);
 21
 22  end;
 23  /
7369
7499
7521
7566
7654
7698
7782
7788
7839
7844
7876
7900
7902
7934
l_count=6

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: how do you add a number to emplist and select a value from emplist? Can you use an insert into or select statements with emplist as if it was a table,etc?

Comment: There's a complete treatment of object types within PLSQL in the docs https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adobj/using-pl-sql-with--object-types.html#GUID-C70ACBDE-FFCC-495C-931D-07E0D59C92E5, but as others have said, make sure you actually need to head down this path

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a GTT nor a collection to spool the keys. Further even plsql is not necessary; you can do it in a single statement. Since you didn't post where clauses I'll keep the same basic select structure:

```
update table 
   set field = 1 
 where primary_key in  
       ( select primary_keys from table    -- first select    
         union 
         select primary_keys from table    -- second select
       );
```

This likely can be further reduced to a single sub select in the where clause connected with an OR.

```
update table 
   set field = 1 
 where primary_key in  
       ( select primary_keys from table      
          where (clause form first select)   
             or (clause form second select) 
       );
```

Depending on those clauses perhaps reduced to:

```
update table 
   set field = 1 
 where (clause form first select)   
    or (clause form second select);
```

But I would need those clauses to make that determination.

Comment: I want to do more than just update a field with these stored numbers, I would also like to do some inserts,etc. so I would prefer to iterate over the stored cache to do appropriate inserts,updates,etc

Comment: Then, in the future, put that type information in your description of what you are attempting. It is difficult to give a good answer when we only have part of the requirements. Glad you got an answer anyhow.